# Multithreaded programming with libmysql

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, pthreads, libmysql

I'm using libmysql in a simple multithreaded app which will run on a uni-core embedded system processor.
I read [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/c-api-threaded-clients.html) that the client library is *almost* thread-safe.

Do I need to serialise my app (say, with a mutex)?

Comment: you should really read the page you linked. it has all the info.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depends on what you're doing. In a simple scenario you'd just link against `libmysqlclient_r` and make sure you don't share a connection with multiple threads nor execute multiple queries "simultaneously" on a single connection.

Other requirements:

1. Before creating any threads, call `mysql_library_init()` to initialise the MySQL library;
2. On each thread call `mysql_thread_init()` to initialise thread-specific variables before using any MySQL related functions;
3. Before destroying a thread, call `mysql_thread_end()`.

If your program is respecting these limitations, MySQL is your friend.